# `debug_backtrace()` reports abstract classes in trace rather than concrete classes. Is there a fix?

Tags: php, abstract-class, stack-trace, debug-backtrace, concreteclass

I wrote the following code which turns the result of `debug_backtrace()` into a string:

```
function debug_backtrace_string($skip = 1)
{
    try
    {
        $calls = debug_backtrace();
        $calls = array_slice($calls, $skip);
        $str = [];
        foreach ($calls as $call)
        {
            if (isset($call['args']))
                foreach ($call['args'] as $k => $v)
                    $call['args'][$k] = gettype($v).' '.'"'.substr($v, 0, 100).'"';
            else
                $call['args'] = [];
            $str[] = ($call['file']??'')
                    .(isset($call['line'])?' ('.$call['line'].')':'')
                    ." ".($call['class']??'').($call['type']??'').$call['function']
                    .'('.implode(', ', $call['args']).')';
        }
        return implode("\n", $str);
    }
    catch (Throwable $e)
    {
        return "debug_backtrace_string($skip) failed: ".$e;
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm trying to debug quite a lot of code in an abstract class, and it's extended by 3 classes. But more often than not, the above code spits out the name of the abstract class rather than the concrete class, and it's really making life difficult because I'm having trouble differentiating which concrete class is doing what.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the abstract/concrete classes you're talking about?

Comment: Is this a rough example of your problem, where `C` is completely missing? https://3v4l.org/SO1cE#v8.2.6

Comment: If so, one option, a little hacky, is to use `static::class` at the call-site: https://3v4l.org/p0QTD#v8.2.6. With lots of abstract classes in the chain it only gets the last unfortunately